# Results Limit for Expanded Field

Tags: list, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, row-limit, expand

I need to get all items for a series of lists and I'm hoping to do this in a single call to the REST API. Right now I can get all lists within a site *and* get can each list's content by using $expand=Items.

The issue is that SharePoint is limiting the "Items" to 100 results (I need all items -- it should never hit that 5k SharePoint threshold but will almost always be more than 100). Here's what it looks like now:

```
SITE_WITH_MANY_LISTS/_api/web/lists?$expand=Items&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&$top=1000
```

I think I'm probably missing something obvious so forgive me if that's the case. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way in Sharepoint, you have to ask for items from each list separately via ..List('')/Items :(
What you can do, is to use batch request.